# What is the reason behind this weird implementation of System.console()?

Tags: java, console, system

I stumbled upon the source code of System.console() and I'm unsure why exactly it is implemented like this:

```
/**
 * Returns the unique {@link java.io.Console Console} object associated
 * with the current Java virtual machine, if any.
 *
 * @return  The system console, if any, otherwise {@code null}.
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
 public static Console console() {
     Console c;
     if ((c = cons) == null) {
         synchronized (System.class) {
             if ((c = cons) == null) {
                 cons = c = SharedSecrets.getJavaIOAccess().console();
             }
         }
     }
     return c;
 }
```

More specifically, what is the point of the assignments to `c`? The variable `cons` is already static and holds the console object.

Comment: It looks like it wants to make sure that the correct `c` is returned, even if `cons` is reassigned in another thread before the return statement is reached.

Comment: @khelwood But couldn't you just wrap the entire method in a synchronized block?

Comment: Yeah if you want the entire method to be synchronized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** It’s a common optimisation technique.

This pattern is called [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

The implementation could also just look much simpler, as follows:

```
public static synchronized Console console() {
    if (cons == null) {
        cons = SharedSecrets.getJavaIOAccess().console();
    }
    return cons;
}
```

However, that way we would *always* lock the entire `System` class for every single call of the `console` method, which would lead to a substantial slowdown in typical applications.

Instead, the actual implementation defensively locks the object *only* if it can’t acquire a valid `cons` instance. And it assigns the result to a local variable `c` so that this instance remains valid even if another thread overrides `cons` after the (unlocked) check happens. It also helps reduce reading the `cons` reference, which is declared as `volatile`, and reading it is thus slower than reading a non-volatile reference.